# Update Golang 1.13 to 1.14

Tags: go

I'm using version : 1.13 now I want to update 1.14 because I want to develop application in wasm, How I can do this [Without uninstall]

Version : 1.13.3/amdlinux
Ubuntu : 1.18.4

Thankyou for your help

Comment: You cannot. You must uninstall first and install afterwards. There is _no_ _point_ in not uninstalling.

Comment: WHY do you want to do this without uninstall? If you need to support both Go 1.13 and 1.14 for different projects on the same machine, consider using [gvm](https://github.com/moovweb/gvm). If you just don't like uninstalling, you'll need to get over that.

Answer (score 1):

You can't without uninstall, at least if you follow the installation method suggested in the official docs.

As the [docs](https://golang.org/doc/install#install) quote:

> If you are upgrading from an older version of Go you must first remove the existing version.

One option you have is to extract the `go1.14` binary to a separate directory not in your `$PATH`, and create a file/symlink `go1.14` in your `$PATH` which points to the actual `go` 1.14 binary.

Comment: That part of the docs is only relevant if you install using the documentation way of installation. If you install it some other way the chance is you may have multiple versions installed simultaneously.

Comment: True, but then you will have to maintain a symlink in your PATH which points to the actual implementation of `go` you want to use.

Comment: Indeed, my point is that "You can't without uninstall" is a bit extreme.

Comment: @zerkms Edited.